# How do I compare a value to a backslash?

Tags: python, syntax

```
if (message.value[0] == "/" or message.value[0] == "\"):
    do stuff.
```

I'm sure it's a simple syntax error, but something is wrong with this if statement.

Comment: Related/duplicate: [How to print backslash with Python?](//stackoverflow.com/q/19095796)

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Escape the backslash:

```
if message.value[0] == "/" or message.value[0] == "\\":
```

From the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals):

> The backslash (\) character is used to
>   escape characters that otherwise have
>   a special meaning, such as newline,
>   backslash itself, or the quote
>   character.

Comment: The parentheses are valid, but meaningless.

Answer (score 61):

When you only need to check for equality, you can also simply use the [`in`](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#in) operator to do a membership test in a sequence of accepted elements:

```
if message.value[0] in ('/', '\\'):
    do_stuff()
```

Comment: Or just `message.value[0] in "/\\":` because strings are iterable.

Comment: If you can be certain that `message.value[0]` is a string of length 1 (yes, I know, I know...).

Comment: message.value[0] in "/\\ can be dangerous - too easy to screw up during maintenance 2 weeks later, or by another programmer.

Comment: If you wanted to allow for `message` being an empty string, the idiom would be `if message.value[:1] in ('/', '\\')`.

Answer (score 2):

Try like this:

```
if message.value[0] == "/" or message.value[0] == "\\":
  do_stuff
```

Answer (score 2):

If message.value[] is string:

```
if message.value[0] in ('/', '\'):
    do_stuff()
```

If it not str

Answer (score 0):

Use following code to perform if-else conditioning in python:
Here, I am checking the length of the string. If the length is less than 3 then do nothing, if more then 3 then I check the last 3 characters. If last 3 characters are "ing" then I add "ly" at the end otherwise I add "ing" at the end.

Code-

```
if (len(s)<=3):
    return s
elif s[-3:]=="ing":
    return s+"ly"
else: return s + "ing"
```